# Compare different vector iterators and erase element from the first vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I've been struggling with this problem for about a week now. I don't know anymore what the problem is or if I update the iterator at the wrong place.

Let's get to the point. I'm trying to make a drop system where random items are being dropped from the monster after the player kills it. I get the items from the container below. After I receive the items from `gear` container, I want to delete received items from the `gear` vector as well. I.e. if "Plate armor" is dropped, I want to delete it from the `gear` container.

I have a vector of Gears where I register different gears such as weapon, armor or accessories. In our case, I will only focus on *Armor*.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Armor>> gear;

/* This is the simplified version of the vector. 
 I register different elements into my gear vector. Now is only armor focused on.
*/
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Great pauldron", 25, 100));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Holy armor", 3, 18));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Dominic's eye", 18, 73));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Plate armor", 23, 21));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Poor armor", 57, 7));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Good shield", 91, 5));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Jodin's boots", 18, 66));
gear.emplace_back(new Armor("Ivona's gauntlets", 25, 100));
```

Next step, I make a class where I receive given the number of items as a vector of a vector iterator. (I use the public function for such operation.)

```
class Maker {
private:

    template<typename Iter, typename RandomGen>
    Iter randomSelection(Iter begin, Iter end, RandomGen& ran) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, std::distance(begin, end) - 1);
        std::advance(begin, dist(ran));
        return begin;
    }
public:

    template<typename Iter>
    std::vector<Iter> randomSelection(Iter& begin, Iter& end, int amount) {
        std::vector<Iter> it;
        std::random_device randDev;
        std::mt19937 gen(randDev());
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            it.push_back(randomSelection<>(begin, end, gen));
        return it;
    }
};
```

Next, I make a vector of vector iterator to receive random items from the `gear` container.

```
Maker mak;
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Armor>>::iterator>& droppedItems = 
    mak.randomSelection(gear.begin(), gear.end(), 5);
```

The problem comes where I try to compare armor names from both vectors and if found; delete it from our very first `gear` vector. I almost always get an access violation error. It sometimes works to delete the items without producing any error. But just once every i.e. 20 tries.

```
for (auto& i = gear.begin(); i != gear.end();) {
        for (auto& j = droppedItems.begin(); j != droppedItems.end(); j++) {
            /* This if statement is where I get the access violation error; 0x05.*/
            if (i->get()->getName() == (*j)->get()->getName()) {
                std::cout << std::endl << i->get()->getName() << " has been deleted!\n";
                i = gear.erase(i);
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
```

I assume I increment the iterator(s) at the wrong place. I assume I perform the erase operation finely but I'm literally out of ideas.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Armor>>::iterator>& droppedItems` is a reference to a temporary? Other than that, you're probably invalidating the rest of the iterators you hold when you `gear.erase(i)`.

Comment: I think the crash comes from the fact that `i` may reach `::end()` and you are trying to dereference it in your if statement... One possibilty would be to check (after calling erase) `if(i == gear.end()) break;` (and stop the loop)

Comment: You are both correct and thank you both for the great feedback. However, the thing I don't yet understand is where exactly shall I revalidate the `i` iterator after it reaches `::end()`?

Comment: since you erase items from `gear`, that needs to be the inner loop

Comment: Since you may have missed my edit: One possibilty would be to check (after calling erase) `if(i == gear.end()) break;` (and stop the loop) or swap the inner with the outer loop

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert, All of my gears are being deleted when I change the loop order ^^ How??

Comment: What does the `std::cout` generate?

Comment: It echos the name of all the items from the gear container. Like all of them being deleted. Hmmm. As of now, I'm super burned out. I may need some rest. Can't comprehend anything.

Comment: `gear.begin()` should result in a rvalue. not sure why `auto&` works. should be just `auto` anyway.

Comment: switching `auto&` to `auto` and swapping loop order should work. see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f61c67016caf29d5

Comment: Are you aware that `droppedItems` can contain the same item many times, since items aren't removed from the source table until after the drop table is filled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::erase(iter)` invalidates the iterators and references at or after `iter` (including `end()`), but you still attempt to use these invalidated iterators from the `droppedItems` container afterwards.

For example, if lets say that `droppedItems` also contains an iterator pointing to the last element of `gears`, and also some other iterators. When you erase any other element of `gears`, it invalidates the iterator to the last element. So when you finally call `gears.erase()` passing the (invalidated) iterator to the last element, it will cause undefined behavior.

```
std::vector<int> test{1,2,3,4};
auto firstIter = test.begin();
auto secondIter = firstIter + 1;
auto thirdIter = secondIter + 1;
auto fourthIter = thirdIter + 1;
test.erase(secondIter); // Invalidates secondIter, thirdIter and fourthIter
                        // but not firstIter
```

You can think of `std::vector<T>` iterators as pointers to `T`. If you erase an element, the elements following it will be moved in memory to keep the vector elements as a dynamic array. Hence the iterators "pointing" to those elements will not continue to point at the correct elements.

Before `test.erase(secondIter)`:

```
address: | 0x0 | 0x1 | 0x2 | 0x3 |
value:   |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |

firstIter  = 0x0 // Points to element with value 1
secondIter = 0x1 // Points to element with value 2
thirdIter  = 0x2 // Points to element with value 3
fourthIter = 0x3 // Points to element with value 4
```

After `test.erase(secondIter)`:

```
address: | 0x0 | 0x1 | 0x2 |
value:   |   1 |   3 |   4 |

firstIter  = 0x0 // Still points to element with value 1
secondIter = 0x1 // no longer points to element with value 2
thirdIter  = 0x2 // no longer points to element with value 3
fourthIter = 0x3 // out of vector bounds
```

I suggest to instead set random elements of `gears` to `nullptr` and then compact the vector afterwards:

```
template <typename T>
void freeRandomItems(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > & vec,
                     std::size_t amount)
{
    if (amount == 0u)
        return; // Nothing to do

    // Setup RNG:
    std::random_device randDev;
    std::mt19937 gen(randDev());

    if (amount == 1u) { // Remove only one random element:
        vec.erase(randomSelection(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen));
        return;
    }

    // Deallocate amount pointed elements in vector, reset pointers:
    do {
        randomSelection<>(vec.begin(), vec.end(), gen)->reset();
    } while (--amount);

    // Remove all nullptr elements from vec:
    vec.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                    vec.begin(),
                    vec.end(),
                    [](std::unique_ptr<T> const & v) noexcept { return !v; }),
            vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the swift reply. Should I perhaps just make a statement to check whether or not the `droppedItems` iterator `j` is valid by `j != droppedItems.end()` instead of having it inside the inner loop? But why will inner loop iterator `j` get invalidated when I perform the erase operation for outer loop, `i`? Sorry, I may totally miss your point if that's the case I apologize, I'm just totally burned out.

Comment: You can think of `std::vector<T>` iterators as pointers to `T`. If you erase an element, the elements following it will be moved in memory to keep the vector elements as a dynamic array. Hence the iterators "pointing" to those elements will not continue to point at the correct elements.

Comment: @VG Added code for a possible solution to your problem, and now also fixed a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Given your case, doing things in a different way could avoid this re-validation business. You may add elements that don't match in a temporary vector for gear in your nested loop and then move that vector into the original gear vector. Something like this?

**UPDATED:** There was a minor mistake in the posted code. Fixed the same. This code is now working on my machine and giving correct results.

```
decltype(gear) newGearTmp;
//Reserve size for remaining elements in newGearTmp vector
newGearTmp.reserve(gear.size() - droppedItems.size());
for (auto& i = gear.begin(); i != gear.end(); i++) {
    bool lbFound = false;
    for (auto& j = droppedItems.begin(); j != droppedItems.end() && !lbFound; j++) {
        if (i->get()->getName() == (*j)->get()->getName()) {
            std::cout << std::endl << i->get()->getName() << " has been deleted!\n";
            //i = gear.erase(i); //No need for this
            lbFound = true;
        }
    }
    !lbFound ? newGearTmp.push_back(std::move(*i)) : 0;
}
gear = std::move(newGearTmp); //gear now has new armor, unwanted elements are deleted
```

This should not be more performance intensive compared to your current implementation which also involves swapping overhead of elements after erase.

Also, in this part of your code, you should get the vector of dropped items by value and not reference. Like this.

```
Maker mak;
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Armor>>::iterator> droppedItems = 
    mak.randomSelection(gear.begin(), gear.end(), 5);
```

Taking by reference will lead to `droppedItems` pointing to a deleted temporary vector which was alive for the scope of function `mak.randomSelection()`.

One more thing. In your original submitted code, the `i++` seems a bit out of place. It could lead to some comparisons being skipped as `i` is incremented without comparing with all `j`s.

Comment: This is also one possible solution, but it might incur some performance overhead in dynamic memory management, because memory for `newGearTmp` must be allocated (maybe more than once, because `newGearTmp.reserve()` is not used) and memory for the old elements must be deallocated. Allocating new memory might also throw an exception.

Comment: Agree with new memory might throw exception part, but this will reduce code complexity of OP's current implementation. I'll edit my post to add `newGearTmp.reserve()`. I omitted it because I was giving the general way to fix without looking at specific improvements.

Comment: Also, I think performance overhead of erasing multiple elements from `gear` would be significantly more than making a new vector and appending elements due to all the swapping involved. Profiling may help.

Comment: @KapilDhaimade Thanks for posting a possible solution. Yet my program still gives the same error when I tried the exact code above. The same read access violation as I got for the first time from the if statement.

Comment: @VG, Please check now. There were some errors in my posted code. Have fixed my answer and posted the correct code. It's working on my machine. Sorry, hadn't got time to debug it earlier.

Comment: @KapilDhaimade Thanks, mate. Your method worked too. I'm thankful to you. Even though I tried the same method before but the iterators messed it up pretty bad, vector shenanigans... By the way, can you replace break with lbFound condition inside the inner loop like `j != droppedItems.end() && !lbFound;` which is better IMO. I always try to avoid `break` and `continue` whenever possible. Hehe. Also you may replace `if(lbFound == false) {...}` with `!lbFound ? newGearTmp.push_back(std::move(*i)) : 0;`. Less code :)

Comment: @KapilDhaimade Yes, there is significant performance overhead (due to increased algorithmic complexity) if you erase N elements from a `std::vector` using N `erase()` calls. This is why `std::remove_if` move-partitions the elements to be removed to the end of the given range, which allows for a single `erase()` call to just cut off the tail of the vector. And because the vector elements are of type `std::unique_ptr`, moving/swapping them has very low overhead.

Comment: @jotik, Agreed. I was referring to earlier logic without std::remove_if. The updated logic is great!

Comment: @VG, Incorporated your suggestions in my code. Though I'd say using `break` is just a matter of preference.

Comment: @KapilDhaimade My professors back in my day always discouraged us from using it ^^.  You're perfectly right, it is a matter of preference.